# OSX Lion SFTP Chroot

Tags: mac-osx, sftp, osx-lion

I am looking to allow my SFTP users on my OSX Lion box to be chrooted so they cannot see anything else.

I know about the usual changes in the sshd_config that match the user and set the chroot directory. My issue is that the users cannot write to the set chroot directory.

Has anyone has done this and can shed a light on how they did it?